# Kill a unix process by determining the process id using pidof

Tags: linux, unix

I am trying to kill a process on a node by running

```
kill -9 | pidof process
```

However, this does not seem to work.

There is a poosibility of multiple processes being available.

So I wrote this script, but I am getting an error saying kill_processes is not a command.

```
kill_processes = $(pidof process)
tlen = ${kill_processes[@]}
echo $tlen;
while( tlen > 0) do
echo ${kill_processes[tlen]};
kill -9 ${kill_processes[tlen]}
tlen--;
end
```

Can someone please help me out here ? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most simple solution is

```
kill -9 $(pidof process)
```

When you want to catch the case when there are no such processes you can do

```
pids=$(pidof process) && kill -9 $pids
```

Your script has some syntactic errors (e.g. the '=' must not be surrounded by spaces)

Comment: What a blunder. Never worked on shell script before. Thanks a lot.